# Ctypes, IndexError: list index out of range

Tags: python, ctypes, python-3.5

The range is 20 so I'm not sure where this error is coming from. Added print list length

Error is in the second line. How I call the code:

```
plist = StreamingParameterList()
print(len(plist))
plist = [plist[x] for x in [2,4,12,13,14]]
```

Print length shows 159

StreamingParameterList() contents

```
def StreamingParameterList():
    """ returns a list of all available streaming parameter names """
    num, length = get_parameter_list_size()
    splist = []

    for id in range(num):
        splist.append(get_parameter_list_item(id, length)[0])

    return splist
```

exact error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "testStream.py", line 27, in (module)
    plist = [plist[x] for x in [2,4,12,13,14]]
  File "testStream.py", line 27, in (listcomp)
    plist = [plist[x] for x in [2,4,12,13,14]]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Comment: If you do `print(len(plist))` right after `plist = StreamingParameterList()`, what does it say?

Comment: you say "the range is 20" but I see no evidence of you verifying that in your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your range is not 20, that's the only way your index can be out of bounds.  Either it is empty or it is less than 15.

You can verify this by adding this immediately before the second line:

```
print len(plist)
```

This will verify that the length is not greater than 15

Comment: Just kidding. still not working. Edited original post to show. print len(plist) shows 159

Comment: try accessing plist[14].  Does plist[14] throw an IndexError?

Comment: Python wouldn't throw an IndexError unless your index was out of bounds.  Something in your code is creating invalid indices.

Comment: I'm getting an OSerror 0x00000018 when I call p=StremingParameterList() that I wasn't getting earlier. I made a new post about that one since it's a rather large issue.